# Extracting Twitter PIN info, WP7

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, twitter

I've been following this great tutorial:

http://buildmobile.com/twitter-in-a-windows-phone-7-app/#fbid=o0eLp-OipGa

But it seems that the pin extraction method used in doesn't work for me or is out of date. I'm not an expert on html scrapping and was wondering if someone could help me find a solution to extracting the pin. The method used by the tutorial is:

```
private void BrowserNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e){
if (AuthenticationBrowser.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) {
    AuthenticationBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("https://", "http://") == AuthorizeUrl) {
    var htmlString = AuthenticationBrowser.SaveToString();
    var pinFinder = new Regex(@"<DIV id=oauth_pin>(?<pin>[A-Za-z0-9_]+)</DIV>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var match = pinFinder.Match(htmlString);
    if (match.Length > 0) {
        var group = match.Groups["pin"];
        if (group.Length > 0) {
            pin = group.Captures[0].Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin)) {
                RetrieveAccessToken();
            }
        }
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin)){
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Authorization denied by user"));
    }
    // Make sure pin is reset to null
    pin = null;
    AuthenticationBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

}

When running through that code, "match" always ends up null and the pin is never found. Everything else in the tutorial works, but I have no idea how to manipulate this code to extract the pin due to the new structure of the page.

I really appreciate the time,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that Twitter has 2 different PIN pages, and I think they determine which page to redirect you to depending on your browser.

Something as simple as string parsing will work for you. The first PIN page I came across has the PIN code wrapped in a <.code>  tag, so simply look for <.code> and parse it out:

```
 if (innerHtml.Contains("<code>"))
 {
     pin = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("<code>") + 6, 7);
 }
```

The other page I came across (which looks like the one in the tutorial you are using) is wrapped using an id="oauth_pin" if I recall correctly. So, just parse that as well:

```
else if(innerHtml.Contains("oauth_pin"))
{
     pin = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("oauth_pin") + 10, 7);
}
```

innerHtml is a string that contains the body of the page. Which seems to be var htmlString = AuthenticationBrowser.SaveToString(); from your code.

I use both of these in my C# program and they work great, full snippet:

```
private void WebBrowser1DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      var innerHtml = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.ToLower();
      var code = string.Empty;
      if (innerHtml.Contains("<code>"))
      {
          code = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("<code>") + 6, 7);
      }
      else if(innerHtml.Contains("oauth_pin"))
      {
          code = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("oauth_pin") + 10, 7);
      }
      textBox1.Text = code;
}
```

Let me know if you have any question and I hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I need to change the code suggested from Toma A with this one:

```
   var innerHtml = webBrowser1.SaveToString();
        var code = string.Empty;

        if (innerHtml.Contains("<code>"))
        {
            code = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("<code>") + 6, 7);

        }

        else if (innerHtml.Contains("oauth_pin"))
        {
            code = innerHtml.Substring(innerHtml.IndexOf("oauth_pin") + 10, 7);
        }
```

because this one doesn't works for windows phone

```
 var innerHtml = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.ToLower();
```